# COPY INTO Snowflake Table with Extra Columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a table defined in Snowflake as:

#### GLPCT

```
BATCH_KEY NUMBER(38,0) NULL
CTACCT VARCHAR(100) NULL
CTPAGE NUMBER(38,0) NULL
```

and a file that looks like this:

#### GLPCT.csv

```
CTACCT VARCHAR(100)
CTPAGE NUMBER(38,0)
```

example:

```
CTACCT,CTPAGE
"Test Account",100
"Second Account", 200
```

My copy into command looks like this:

```sql
copy into GLPCT_POC from 'azure://ouraccount.blob.core.windows.net/landing/GLPCT' credentials=(azure_sas_token='<SAS_TOKEN') file_format=(TYPE=CSV, SKIP_HEADER = 1, FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"');
```

### Problem

Snowflake is throwing an error due to a column number mismatch. How can I get Snowflake to ignore the column that isn't present in the file and not throw an error? I can move `BATCH_KEY` to the end of the table if that will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears it's possible to indicate what columns to insert into with a COPY INTO statement, so ours becomes:

```sql
copy into GLPCT_POC (CTACCT, CTPAGE) from 'azure://ouraccount.blob.core.windows.net/landing/GLPCT' credentials=(azure_sas_token='<SAS_TOKEN') file_format=(TYPE=CSV, SKIP_HEADER = 1, FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"');
```

We could not use a transformation as mentioned in a previous answer, due to this being an external file.

Comment: I didn't know about this, that's a nice way to do this for simple, one off copy queries. I'll just add the note that it's generally recommended to use stages for production environments to improve maintenance, resuability, modularity.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a "transformation" as you pull data in with a copy into query. In this case your transformation can be to add a NULL column.

However, in order to use this feature, you need to create a stage for your external source

```
create or replace stage my_stage 
url='azure://ouraccount.blob.core.windows.net/landing/GLPCT'
credentials=(azure_sas_token='<SAS_TOKEN')
file_format=(TYPE=CSV, SKIP_HEADER = 1, FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"');

copy into GLPCT_POC 
from (SELECT NULL, $1, $2 FROM @my_stage);
```

The $1 and $2 line up with the columns in the file, and then the order of the columns in the select clause line up with the columns of the table.

The extra benefit of this is if you are reusing that copy statement and/or stage, you don't need to have all the credential and file format information repeated.

See [Data load with transformation syntax](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#syntax)

Comment: It appears, from the documentation, that they COPY INTO command doesn't support transformations when using an external source. I tried your command above and received this error: `SQL compilation error: COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import.`

Comment: ah yes. I forgot. to do this, you need to set up a stage as an extra step. Updating my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> *How can I get Snowflake to ignore the column that isn't present in the file and not throw an error?*

It is possible by using [MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table#copy-options-copyoption) parameter:

> ```
> MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_SENSITIVE | CASE_INSENSITIVE | NONE
> ```
>
> Definition
>
> String that specifies whether to load semi-structured data into columns in the target table that match corresponding columns represented in the data.

[Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema#usage-notes)

> For loading CSV files, the `MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME` copy option is available in preview. It requires the use of the above-mentioned CSV file format option `PARSE_HEADER = TRUE`.

The COPY command:

```
COPY INTO GLPCT_POC FROM 'azure://ouraccount.blob.core.windows.net/landing/GLPCT' 
credentials=(azure_sas_token='<SAS_TOKEN>') 
file_format=(TYPE=CSV, PARSE_HEADER = TRUE, FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"')
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake allows you to set the ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH in the file format.

> ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE | FALSE Boolean that specifies
> whether to generate a parsing error if the number of delimited columns
> (i.e. fields) in an input data file does not match the number of
> columns in the corresponding table.
>
> If set to FALSE, an error is not generated and the load continues. If
> the file is successfully loaded:
>
> If the input file contains records with more fields than columns in
> the table, the matching fields are loaded in order of occurrence in
> the file and the remaining fields are not loaded.
>
> If the input file contains records with fewer fields than columns in
> the table, the non-matching columns in the table are loaded with NULL
> values.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-csv